# No Instance Found When Using "always"

Tags: alloy

I'm trying to visualise a spec for a Payment object where it moves from "queued" to "processing" to "complete". I have come up with the following:

```
enum State {Queued, Processing, Complete}

sig Payment {
    var state: State
}

pred processPayment[p: Payment] {
    p.state = Queued // guard
    p.state' = Processing // action
}

pred completePayment[p: Payment] {
    p.state = Processing // guard
    p.state' = Complete // action
}

fact init {
    Payment.state = Queued
}

fact next {
    always (some p : Payment | processPayment[p] or completePayment[p])
}

run {} for 1 Payment
```

Unfortunately, I get no instances found for this spec. From my understanding, a Payment with state "Queued" initially and a next state where it's in "Processing" should be allowed with the `always (some p : Payment | processPayment[p] or completePayment[p])"` formula according to the tutorial at https://haslab.github.io/formal-software-design/overview/index.html. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be a missing terminating predicate, adding the below(or a stutter) fixes it.

```
pred afterComplete[p: Payment] {
    p.state = Complete // guard
    p.state' = Complete // action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but I believe that it is impossible for either of your predicates to be true at t0.  I think you need a `holdPayment` predicate like this:

```
pred holdPayment[p:Payment] {
  p.state = p.state'
}

fact next {
   always (some p : Payment | processPayment[p] or completePayment[p] or holdPayment[p])
}

run {} for 1 Payment
```

Comment: Thanks, I've found the issue. t0's state is fine, but there's no way for transitions to occur after "completePayment", adding a event to handle that(more explicit) or a stutter fixes the issue.